# Formatting an value array in xslt 1.0

Tags: arrays, xslt, xslt-1.0

Could any good soul help me in the situation below?

I have this xml below that some fields are an array and I need to take the Value of these fields and concatenate separated by comma in xslt 1.0

Input XML

< io>
< key name="PeriodoInicial" value="2020-08-01"/ >
< key name="PeriodoFinal" value="2020-08-04"/ >
< key name="PartNumber" value="LIC-CUCM-12X-ESS"/>
< key name="NumeroProposta" value="34887"/>
< key name="CnpjCliente" value="59.285.411/0001-13"/>
< key name="NomeCliente" value="BANCO PAN S.A."/>
< key name="PO" value="1"/>
< key name="SO" value="2"/>
< key name="ShipmentId" value="12345"/>
< key name="CodigoTipoProduto" value="100"/>
< key name="CodigoTipoProduto" value="103"/>
< key name="CodigoFilial" value="1"/>
< key name="CodigoFilial" value="3"/>
< key name="CodigoVendedor" value="34"/>
< key name="CodigoVendedor" value="37"/>
< key name="CodigoVendedor" value="38"/>
< /io>

How do I expect the array values ​​to exit

< out>
< CodigoTipoProduto>100.103< /CodigoTipoProduto>
< CodigoFilial>1.3< /CodigoFilial>
< CodigoVendedor>34,37,38< /CodigoVendedor>
< /out>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>  
    
    <xsl:template match="/io">
      <out>
        <CodigoTipoProduto><xsl:for-each select="key[@name='CodigoTipoProduto']"><xsl:value-of select="@value" /><xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" /></xsl:if></xsl:for-each></CodigoTipoProduto>
        <CodigoFilial><xsl:for-each select="key[@name='CodigoFilial']"><xsl:value-of select="@value" /><xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" /></xsl:if></xsl:for-each></CodigoFilial>
        <CodigoVendedor><xsl:for-each select="key[@name='CodigoVendedor']"><xsl:value-of select="@value" /><xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" /></xsl:if></xsl:for-each></CodigoVendedor>    
      </out>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<out>
  <CodigoTipoProduto>100.103</CodigoTipoProduto>
  <CodigoFilial>1.3</CodigoFilial>
  <CodigoVendedor>34.37.38</CodigoVendedor>
</out>
```